# Make button width equal DIFFERENT text width (not the button's text) on Android

Tags: android

Right now my Log In button is wider than my app name text because it uses fixed padding of the relative layout, but I want it to automatically widen to line up with the left and right edges of the app name text. Is there any way to programmatically do this?

I want it to look the same on all devices. I'm afraid that if I just hard-code my own margins, it will look right on my device, but might not look right on other devices if they render the fonts differently.

Thanks!

layout.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:background="@drawable/back_image"
android:padding="20dp" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/AppNameTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
    android:fontFamily="Arial"
    android:text="@string/app_title"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

    <com.timey.widget.Button
    android:id="@+id/signInButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:background="@color/green"
    android:fontFamily="Arial"
    android:text="@string/sign_in"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Mockup with red dash lines illustrating how I want the sides of the app name to line up with the sides of my log-in button:

[image]

Comment: Try using Linear layout

Comment: How would that make them have the same widths?

Comment: Wait giving you the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure if this would help, but let me give it a try.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="App\nTitle" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/title"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/title"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:text="Log In" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

However, the button would be just as wide as the textview, it may not be wide enough to display its own text.

Comment: care to explain the downvote? it works fine when I tested it on my machine

Comment: Yes it perfectly works fine, @CChi. +1 from me. Though it's similar to mine ;-). Why down vote?

Comment: The outcome may be similar, but i think relativelayout is a requirement.

Comment: I just had to add these: android:layout_alignLeft="@id/title" and android:layout_alignRight="@id/title", and it made it work. Thank you CChi!

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The first button will take as much space it will need. Then the next button(or what ever your case) will take as much space as it's parent (linear layout) will take which on the other side will wrap the content i.e. the width of first button. So both the buttons will take same width. You can use this to any other components.

**Update1**

```
Key to the success
1. A container with wrap_content
2. First component should have wrap_content
3. Second component should have match_content
```

**Update2**
for RelativeLayout use layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1" and layout_alignRight="@+id/button1" 
It will align to the left and right of the first component i.e. button1 here.

Comment: I'm not using 2 buttons though. I'm trying to line up text and a button.

Comment: The concept will do fine to any components as mentioned in the answer above

Comment: I need to use a RelativeLayout, not a LinearLayout.

Comment: To use RelativeLayout use layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        and layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"

Comment: it will align to the left and right of the first component i.e. button1 here. Hope it works fine to you. Let me know if it works. Good luck