# How to match the widths of two TextViews in android using xml alone

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have two string resources. However I don't know which of the two strings would produce the wider TextView. I want to create two TextViews, one on top of the other, one using the text of the first resource, and the other using the text of the second resource. I want the TextViews to be the same width, but no wider than necessary.

I can achieve this. I use a layout resource that looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/green_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:text="@string/green_text"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/blue_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/green_text_view"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/green_text_view"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:text="@string/blue_text"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and I make the widths match in onCreate(), by using code like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TextView greenTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.green_text_view);
    TextView blueTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.blue_text_view);
    greenTextView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    blueTextView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    int maxWidth = Math.max(greenTextView.getMeasuredWidth(), blueTextView.getMeasuredWidth());
    greenTextView.setWidth(maxWidth);
    blueTextView.setWidth(maxWidth);
}
```

It works. The TextViews are aligned and centred whichever TextView is naturally wider.

My question: is it possible to do this using xml alone? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make button width equal DIFFERENT text width (not the button's text) on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25539485/make-button-width-equal-different-text-width-not-the-buttons-text-on-android)

Comment: It's a slightly different question to that one as in that question the top text view was definitely wider. I don't think any of the xml answers to that question work if the bottom one is wider, that's why I asked it as a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems impossible. As you don't know which one will be naturally wider, `RelativeLayout` (and you) can't tell the dependency between the two. If you accidentally use `layout_align*`attribute to align the wider View `B` with the normal one, the content of `B` will be clipped.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/green_text_view"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/green_text_view"
```

I haven't tested it though

Comment: You can use  

    android:minWidth = "" 

on the top text view

Answer (score 0):

```
Change the layout_width of RelativeLayout to wrap_content
Change the layout_width of second textview to match_parent
```

This works perfectly fine if your second textView content is smaller than first . Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25539485/make-button-width-equal-different-text-width-not-the-buttons-text-on-android/25539536#25539536) for better solution .

Comment: @suitianshi that's why i gave a link to another answer, that i answer few hours ago

Answer (score 0):

Inside the RelativeLayout put a vertical LinearLayout with android:layout_width="wrap_content" and inside the 2 TextViews with android:layout_width="match_parent".